# Need to Limit characters in Sharepoint in Hyperlink field description

Tags: hyperlink

I need to limit characters in hyperlink field in the hyperlink field it consists with two part one is to enter hyper link and other one in description so I need to keep the url enter part as it is and need to limit description part

Answer (score 0):

The customization of [Hyperlink field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms460596.aspx) on the client side probably the simplest way in that case.

For example, in order limit description part of Hyperlink field to 4 symbols:

```
function initListForm()
{
   $('input[name$="UrlFieldDescription"]').attr("maxlength", 4); 
}
```

Usage

```
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("initListForm");
```

P.S. For embedding JavaScript code on Edit form use [Delegate Control technique](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2011/04/06/adding-jquery-to-every-page-in-sharepoint-with-delegate-controls.aspx)